# Clang-Tidy `NOLINT` for multiple lines?

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I'm working on a C++ project that has some large sections of code that are autogenerated, and I don't want to be linted. Is there something akin to the `//NOLINT` comment that can be applied to multiple lines? Like the following:

```
// BEGINNOLINT
bad-code;
// ENDNOLINT
```

All I could find online was a [suggestion that this should be implemented](https://reviews.llvm.org/D54757). Is there any way to avoid having to write `// NOLINT` on the end of every single line?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[clang-tidy 14](https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/) introduced this feature:

```cpp
// NOLINTBEGIN
...
// NOLINTEND
```

Note, if you want to disable a specific warning, the end-comment must match the begin-comment:

```cpp
// NOLINTBEGIN(check-name)
...
// NOLINTEND(check-name)
```

Comment: Will  it work for whole include files? As in `// NOLINTBEGIN \\ #include<header> \\ //NOLINTEND` ?

Comment: the checkname in END seems too redundant, is it really necessary?

Comment: Just to confirm, yes, `NOLINTEND` check names must match that of `NOLINTBEGIN` otherwise, the end is not recognized, and one gets this `error: unmatched 'NOLINTBEGIN' comment without a subsequent 'NOLINTEND' comment [clang-tidy-nolint]`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to do this, clang-tidy only supports `//NOLINT` and `//NOLINTNEXTLINE`.

I don't know how much control you have about that code generation...you could generate it in one line, that could help you a lot as c++ doesn't care about whitespace.

A crude but effective solution is to use a text-manipulation tool like sed:

```
$ sed -i -re '/^\/\/BEGIN_NOLINT/,/^\/\/END_NOLINT/{s/$/\/\/NOLINT/}' *.cpp
```

This would add `//NOLINT` at the end of every line between `//BEGIN_NOLINT` and `//END_NOLINT` comments (which can be probably generated).

You can also run clang-tidy with parameter

```
-line-filter='[{"name":"test.cpp","lines":[[1,10],[12,100]]}]'
```

Line 11 will be skipped in this example. This is however difficult to maintain as you need to update the filter every time you add/remove lines in the file. Maybe it would be a good idea to generate code into separate files if possible.

Answer (score -2):

Im sure that, when Im applying `//NOLINTNEXTLINE` on MACRO, so the entire MARCO is skiped. So try to implement `//NOLINTNEXTLINE` to your class or function